# Scala: Implictly convert a list

Tags: scala, implicit

Here is a reduced example of what I want to do. The line commented out doesn't compile.

```
class Animal
object Animal { implicit def toElephant(a: Animal) = a.asInstanceOf[Elephant] }
class Elephant extends Animal

object Main {

    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val a: List[Animal] = List(new Elephant, new Elephant)
        // val e: List[Elephant] = a
    }
}
```

In a regular situation, `e = a` is of course illegal. But with the implicit function, one could think that scala would automatically convert every element in the list.

Is there an elegant way to get this behaviour? If yes, how?

What I wish to know is if there is some obscure corner of scala that can force the behaviour I wish. I am not interested in solutions that add cruft. I can think of them myself. For instance, one could do:

```
object Animal {
    implicit def toElephant(a: Animal) = a.asInstanceOf[Elephant]
    implicit def toElephant(a: List[Animal]) = a.asInstanceOf[List[Elephant]] }
```

and the code above would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forget implicits and mapping and use simply

```
val e = a.asInstanceOf[List[Elephant]]
```

---

BUT, if you insist, you can of course also do this conversion implicitly. Having an implicit from `List[A]` to `List[B]` is no more crufty than an implicit A => B. I wouldn't do this, but if I did I'd generalise it for re-use, importing locally to limit the implicit's scope:

```
object Implicits {
  implicit def AListToBList[A, B <: A](lst: List[A]) = lst.asInstanceOf[List[B]]
}
```

Then at use-site

```
import Implicits._
val a: List[Animal] = List(new Elephant, new Elephant)
val e: List[Elephant] = a
e.head.doSomethingElephanty
```

Be aware of the scope of the import, and stick things within a `locally` block if necessary.

Comment: OK. What I'll do is create a generic trait with the implicit conversion for single elements and arrays and extend it. I guess I should have phrased my question as "how can I get the effect of the implicit list conversion from the single element implicit conversion". This does not quite do that, but is even better in a sense.

Comment: @Norswap add an `(implicit f: A => B)` to the implicit def above. How you want it to work depends on whether what's in the list is actually of the correct type. If it is, as in your example, use the above. If not, you have to create a new list and convert the objects with a `map` (i.e. `lst map f`).

Answer (score 2):

> But with the implicit function, one could think that scala would
>   automatically convert every element in the list.

Why?

Let's try something:

```
class X[T : Manifest] {
  override def toString = manifest[T].toString
}

val x = new X[Animal]
```

How will an implicit that converts `Animal` into `Elephant` help convert an `X[Animal]` into an `X[Elephant]`? There isn't even an instance of `Animal` to be converted! But let's put an instance there:

```
class X[T : Manifest](t: T) {
  override def toString = manifest[T].toString + t.toString
}
```

Now we have an instance, but, again, how will Scala convert an `X[Animal]` into an `X[Elephant]`? It can't even get at `t`, because it is private. Let's make it public, then:

```
class X[T : Manifest](val t: T) {
  override def toString = manifest[T].toString + t.toString
}
```

There, it is public. But how would it be converted? One way would be this:

```
new X[Elephant](Animal toElephant x.t)
```

But how would Scala know to do that? Who says that's valid code, or that it is enough?

One could write an implicit teaching `X` how to convert itself if another implicit conversion is present, and an implicit like that could exist for `List`, but implicit conversions are dangerous. The less of them there are, the better. And, therefore, such an implicit does not exist.

Comment: It was a purposefully reduced example. In practice I know that the conversion can be done (I check it beforehand). See my answer to Tomasz Nurkiewicz for more context). By the way, feel free to comment on the design I explain in that answer.

I know there's many misguided people out there, but sometimes I wish people would answer the question asked instead of always asking why :)

Comment: @Norswap I ask why to get you to question assumptions you may have. It's often the case that, when someone can't solve a problem, it is the assumptions that are incorrect.

Comment: +1 very good point. This is a common misconception with monads: `Foo[Bar]` does not necessarily mean there is a `Bar` inside of a `Foo`. It simply means the `Foo` is parameterized on `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

What about `map`?

```
val e = a map {_.asInstanceOf[Elephant]}
```

or even better:

```
val e = a collect {case e: Elephant => e}
```

Note that both `asInstanceOf` and an implicit conversion for super-type to sub-type is not very ellegant.

Comment: My answer wound up a little bit long-winded, so here it is: http://pastebin.com/4riHYLZW